Python code does not work inside SD Webui extension for caption detection from generated images using hugging face transformers
I have the following python code:
import os
from transformers import AutoProcessor, LlavaForConditionalGeneration
import transformers
import time
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import json
from typing import Union, List
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import torch
import re
import logging

def load_image(image_path_or_url: str) -> Image.Image:
    if image_path_or_url.startswith(('http://', 'https://')):
        response = requests.get(image_path_or_url)
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    else:
        image = Image.open(image_path_or_url)
    return image   

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def generate_image_caption(image_path_or_url: str, model_id: str = "llava-hf/llava-1.5-7b-hf") -> List[str]:
    try:
        raw_image = load_image(image_path_or_url)
        model = LlavaForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_id, torch_dtype=torch.float16, low_cpu_mem_usage=True, load_in_4bit=True)
        processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained(model_id)

        prompt = "USER: <image>\nWhat is your assessment for this image?\nASSISTANT:"
        inputs = processor(prompt, raw_image, return_tensors='pt').to("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu", torch.float16)
        
        output = model.generate(**inputs, max_new_tokens=300, do_sample=False)
        captions_text = processor.decode(output[0][2:], skip_special_tokens=True)
        
        captions_cleaned = re.sub(r'^.*?ASSISTANT: ', '', captions_text, flags=re.DOTALL)
        sentences = [sentence.strip() for sentence in re.split(r'(?<=[.])\s+', captions_cleaned) if sentence]

        safe_texts = []
        for sentence in sentences:
            safe_text = sentence.replace("'", "''")
            safe_texts.append(safe_text)
        
        return safe_texts
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error generating caption: {e}")
        raise

for t in generate_image_caption(image_path_or_url = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/sd_webui/webui/output/extras-images/00003.png"):
    print(t)

The Code works fine inside Ipython notebook but when I try to add the code to an Stable diffusion WebUI Extension I ger the following error:
ERROR:detect-objects-captions.py:Error generating caption: Object of type LlamaConfig is not JSON serializable
*** Error executing callback app_started_callback for C:\Users\User\Desktop\sd_webui\webui\extensions\sd-webui-extension-detect-objects-captions\scripts\detect-objects-captions.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\sd_webui\webui\modules\script_callbacks.py", line 153, in app_started_callback
        c.callback(demo, app)
      File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\sd_webui\webui\extensions\sd-webui-extension-detect-objects-captions\scripts\detect-objects-captions.py", line 287, in run_detection
        safe_texts = generate_image_caption(image_path_or_url = path_to_watch3+"/"+f, model_id = "llava-hf/llava-1.5-7b-hf")
      File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\sd_webui\webui\extensions\sd-webui-extension-detect-objects-captions\scripts\detect-objects-captions.py", line 69, in generate_image_caption
        model = LlavaForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_id, torch_dtype=torch.float16, low_cpu_mem_usage=True, load_in_4bit=True)
      File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\sd_webui\webui\extensions\sd-webui-extension-detect-objects-captions\scripts\transformers\modeling_utils.py", line 3006, in from_pretrained
        config, model_kwargs = cls.config_class.from_pretrained(
      File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\sd_webui\webui\extensions\sd-webui-extension-detect-objects-captions\scripts\transformers\configuration_utils.py", line 609, in from_pretrained
        return cls.from_dict(config_dict, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\sd_webui\webui\extensions\sd-webui-extension-detect-objects-captions\scripts\transformers\configuration_utils.py", line 789, in from_dict
        logger.info(f"Model config {config}")
      File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\sd_webui\webui\extensions\sd-webui-extension-detect-objects-captions\scripts\transformers\configuration_utils.py", line 821, in __repr__
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__} {self.to_json_string()}"
      File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\sd_webui\webui\extensions\sd-webui-extension-detect-objects-captions\scripts\transformers\configuration_utils.py", line 938, in to_json_string
        return json.dumps(config_dict, indent=2, sort_keys=True) + "\n"
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
        **kw).encode(obj)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 201, in encode
        chunks = list(chunks)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 431, in _iterencode
        yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 405, in _iterencode_dict
        yield from chunks
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
        o = _default(o)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
        raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
    TypeError: Object of type LlamaConfig is not JSON serializable

Any Idea why it is not working inside SD Webui extension and how to fix? Thanks
